# How do use BLE scan_stop

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, keil

im doing a program that allow my beacon and DK board to start scanning and stop scanning using BLE. I am able to start scanning, but i didn't know how to stop scanning. Can anyone advise me with this? The code provided is my scan_start. Thank you!

```
static void scan_start(void)
{

    uint32_t err_code;

    err_code = sd_ble_gap_scan_start(&m_scan_params);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

    err_code = bsp_indication_set(BSP_INDICATE_SCANNING);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation/api reference?

Comment: as in, i do not how to start with the code to stop scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping scan_start depends on where you use this function. For example if you use scan_start in main function(before for loop), after a while, if there is no connection, it will enter sleep mode and stop scanning.

Otherwise if you want to control start_scanning time, you can define app_timer function. For example, you can define a timer or button handler that starts scanning when the button is pressed.

If you still can not find the answer you're looking for, there is another suggestion. You can use the stop_scanning function in the file "ble_gap.h" to stop scanning. Function like this;

```
SVCALL(SD_BLE_GAP_SCAN_STOP, uint32_t, sd_ble_gap_scan_stop(void));
```

You can use like this;

```
(void) sd_ble_gap_scan_stop();
```

If there is any mistake please correct it. I hope that will be useful...